# How to store values in a list that were inputed through the input command

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, for-loop, input

if you are inputing 12 values like the months of the year via a for loop to reduce repetition how to get all of the numbers assigned to a list in order of entry, also say you have the list how do you add up all the items within a list
[1,2,3]  total would be: 6

```
for month in range(12):
    whatever = float(input("enter whatever in 12 months: "))

 syntax to put above 12 values into a list
```

Comment: Take a look at sum and append functions defined over python lists

Comment: If you're not sure how to do either of those things, I'd high recommend doing a python tutorial to give you a solid basis before you try stack overflow.

Comment: Will do,  sorry about that. and thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Initialise a list and then use `list.append`:

```
lst = []

for m in range(12):
    lst.append(float(input('Enter entry for month {0}: '.format(m))))
```

Alternatively, you can use a list comprehension, but this is inadvisable as it is a less readable solution:

```
lst = [float(input('Enter entry for month {0}: '.format(m))) for m in range(2)]
```